# Joining parts of lists with specific tags and creating a new list in Python

Tags: python, list

I am new to Python, and I faced with a problem.
I used StanfordNER in Python to tag a text , the output of the name entities are like the following:

```
[('Micheal', 'PERSON'),
 ('Jaf', 'PERSON'),
 ('Bin', 'PERSON'),
 ('Aloo', 'PERSON'),
 ('and', 'O'),
 ('Purno', 'PERSON'),
 ('Yusgiantoro', 'PERSON'),
 ('USA', 'LOCATION'),
 ('Ibrahim', 'PERSON'),
 ('Baah', 'PERSON'),
 ('Alolom', 'PERSON'),
 ('or', 'O'),
 ('Ahmad', 'PERSON'),
 ('Fahad', 'PERSON'),
 ('Al', 'PERSON'),
 ('Ahmad', 'PERSON'),
 ('in', 'O'),
 ('the', 'O'),
 ('Sabah', 'PERSON'),
 ('Purnomo', 'PERSON'),
 ('Khorabi', 'PERSON'),
 ('Elie', 'PERSON')]
```

I would like to join first names and family names of each person and get a list that looks like:

```
persons_names = ['Micheal Jaf Bin Aloo',
         'Purno Yusgiantoro',
         'Ibrahim Baah Alolom',
          'Ahmad Fahad Al Ahmad ' 
         'Sabah Purnomo Khorabi Elie']
```

Comment: Do you mean the 'micheal' in your result to be 'Micheal'? Do you mean all names and connectors to be strings, or are they all variable names? (If not variable names, your data has bad syntax.) Is your data line `myList = ...`? Is the result variable `persons_names`?

Comment: Please post the actual output, what you posted is replete with syntax errors.

Comment: Fixed the syntax errors in your sample input and expected output. Please be more careful next time and don't hand-type this stuff. You gave us a lot of extra work to do because we had to fix numerous mistakes before we could even start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do

```
last=None
grouped=[]
for word,t in myList:
    if t==last:
        grouped[-1].append(word)
    else:
        grouped.append([t,word])
        last=t
person_names=[" ".join(i[1:]) for i in grouped if i[0]=="PERSON"]
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have posted in the question is not a valid python object. It is most probably a `str` version of something. The snippet below assumes the first element of every word is converted to a string.

The idea is to use `itertools.groupby`. It groups adjacent elements according a given condition, and returns one group at a time. All that remains is to join them with a space.

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = [("Micheal", 'PERSON'),("Jaf", 'PERSON'), ("Bin", 'PERSON'),("Aloo", 'PERSON'),("and", 'O'),("Purno", 'PERSON'), ("Yusgiantoro", 'PERSON'),("USA", 'LOCATION'),("Ibrahim", 'PERSON'), ("Baah", 'PERSON'), ("Alolom", 'PERSON'),("or", 'O'),("Ahmad", 'PERSON'),("Fahad", 'PERSON'),("Al", 'PERSON'),("Ahmad", 'PERSON')]

print [" ".join(x[0] for x in names) 
          for typ, names in groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x[1]) 
          if typ == "PERSON"]
```

OUTPUT:

```
['Micheal Jaf Bin Aloo', 'Purno Yusgiantoro', 'Ibrahim Baah Alolom', 'Ahmad Fahad Al Ahmad']
```